# How Am I Changing "this" in Method append(int n)?

Tags: java, linked-list, this

I initialized LinkedNode "node" to become keyword "this" and then I append the new node, "last", to the end of the created node, "node". But notice also in the while loop I change "node" to become "node.next". Why does it print the correct result when I run the program? Maybe I don't understand "this" very well.

```
public class LinkedNode {

    protected LinkedNode next;
    protected int data;

    LinkedNode(int d) {
        data = d;
    }

    public void append(int n) {
        LinkedNode node = this;
        LinkedNode last  = new LinkedNode(n);
        while (node.next != null) {
            node = node.next;
        }
        node.next = last;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LinkedNode Node = new LinkedNode(2);
        Node.append(3);
        Node.append(4);
        Node.append(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            System.out.println("Data: "+Node.data);
            Node = Node.next;
        }
    }
    //Output is correctly "2 3 4 5"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't know whether you understand "this", but what I suspect is that you do not understand java.

In the `append()` function, `node` is a pointer to object of type `LinkedNode`. Initially, the pointer is set to point to the same location as the `this` pointer, so it points to the current object.

Then, within the loop, the `node` pointer is set to point to other things, and in the last line a new value ("last") is stored in one of the fields of the object which happens to be pointed by the `node` pointer after the loop.

If the loop did not loop at all, then `node` is still pointing at the current object, so the current object is modified.  If the loop looped one or more times, then `node` is pointing to some other object, so that other object is modified.

No attempt whatsoever is made, at any moment, to change the `this` pointer, and no such attempt could be made, as that would be illegal in java.